# Unique index in mongoDB 3.2 ignoring null values

Tags: mongodb, indexing, database

I want to add the unique index to a field ignoring null values in the unique indexed field and ignoring the documents that are filtered based on partialFilterExpression.

The problem is Sparse indexes can't be used with the Partial index.

Also, adding unique indexes, adds the null value to the index key field and hence the documents can't be ignored based on $exist criteria in the PartialFilterExpression.

Is it possible in MongoDB 3.2 to get around this situation?

Comment: Does the null value have any special meaning in your case? If not, you can always $unset the field for all null values which makes it possible to use the $exist operator.

Comment: Adding unique index auto adds the null field so we can't have documents without having unique indexed key field.

Answer (score 64):

I am adding this answer as I was looking for a solution and didn't find one. This may not answer exactly this question or may be, but will help lot of others out there like me.

Example. If the field with `null` is `houseName` and it is of type `string`, the solution can be like this

```
db.collectionName.createIndex(
   {name: 1, houseName: 1},
   {unique: true, partialFilterExpression: {houseName: {$type: "string"}}}
);
```

This will ignore the `null` values in the field `houseName` and still be unique.

Comment: Just a note from my testing for anyone else looking for the same solution: although this worked as a mechanism for enforcing uniqueness while allowing nulls, Mongo didn't use the index for lookup queries using the indexed field and using hint() to force it resulted in very slow performance

Comment: @PeteS I saw the same behaviour, did you find a solution that works?

Comment: @MattOakley Not exactly. We went with a workaround solution of setting partialFilterExpression: { fieldToIndex: { $exists: true } } on the index then decorating the corresponding property in our class in the app code with [BsonIgnoreIfNull] (C#). The Mongo driver will then not serialize the field if it's null in the app when saving.

Comment: If partial index contains `$type: string` you should add this to your query to use index (like `.find({ houseName: { $type: "string", $eq: "some value" } })`)

Comment: @PeteS and @oryol are corrects, using `{$type: "string"}` in default requests, not improves performance, must use `{ $exists: true }`

Comment: @Armando has this been resolved by a newer version, or are there any other workarounds? I'm having the same issue but excluding the field is not an option in my case.

Answer (score 8):

You can create partial index in mongo:3.2.
Example, if ipaddress can be "", but "127.0.0.1" should be unique. The solution can be like this:

```
db.collectionName.createIndex(
 {"ipaddress":1},
 {"unique":true, "partialIndexExpression":{"ipaddress":{"$gt":""}}})
```

This will ignore "" values in ipaddress filed and still be unique

Answer (score 8):

Here is an example that I modified from [the mongoDB partial index documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-partial/):

```
db.contacts.createIndex(
   { email: 1 },
   { unique: true, partialFilterExpression: { email: { $exists: true } } }
)
```

**IMPORTANT**

> To use the partial index, a query must contain the filter expression (or a modified filter expression that specifies a subset of the filter expression) as part of its query condition.

You can see that queries such as:

```
db.contacts.find({'email':'name@email.com'}).explain()
```

will indicate that they doing an index scan, even if you don't specify `{$exists: true}` because you're implicitly specifying a subset of the partialFilterExpression by specifying an email in your filter.

On the other hand, the following query will do a collection scan:

```
db.contacts.find({email: {$exists: false}})
```

**WARNING**

mythicalcoder's answer (currently the highest voted answer) is very misleading because it successfully creates a unique index, but the query planner will not generally be able to use the index you've created unless you add `houseName: {$type: "string"}` into your filter expression. This can have performance costs which you might not be aware of and can cause problems down the road.

Comment: This seems to be the best answer 2022+.

Comment: `$exists` doesn't work with `null` values so it's better to use `$type: "string"` instead

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/#mongodb-query-op.-exists. "The 
$exists
 operator matches documents that contain or do not contain a specified field, including documents where the field value is null."

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can create partial index in MongoDB 3.2

Please see https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-partial/#index-type-partial

MongoDB recommend usage of partial index over sparse index. I'll suggest you to drop your sparse index in favor of partial index.

Comment: I have to use PartialFilterExpression to filter data for indexing and on the side have to use the unique index.

Comment: The only thing is I want some documents to not have the unique indexed key field which seems not possible or I may not aware of.

Answer (score 4):

{
"YourField" : {
"$exists" : true,
"$gt" : "0",
"$type" : "string"
}
}

Comment: This answer is perfect if you want an index that is unique for all values that are not equal to an empty string or null.

Answer (score 0):

To create at mongodbCompass you must write it as JSON:

for find other types wich supports see [this link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that can be a kind of a problem that the partial filter expression cannot contain any 'not' filters.

For those who can be interested in a C# solution for an index like this, here is an example.

We have a 'User' entity, which has one-to-one 'relation' to a 'Doctor' entity.
This relation is represented by the not required, nullable field 'DoctorId' in the 'User' entity. In other words, there is a requirement that a given 'Doctor' can be linked to only single 'User' at a time.

So we need an unique index which can fire an exception when something attempts to set DoctorId to the same Guid which already set for any other 'User' entity. At the same time multiple 'null' entries must be allowed for the 'DoctorId' field, since many users do not have any doctor attached to them.

The solution to build this kind of an index looks like:

```
var uniqueDoctorIdIndexDefinition = new IndexKeysDefinitionBuilder<User>()
    .Ascending(o => o.DoctorId);
var existsFilter = Builders<User>.Filter.Exists(o => o.DoctorId);
var notNullFilter = Builders<User>.Filter.Type(o => o.DoctorId, BsonType.String);
var andFilter = Builders<User>.Filter.And(existsFilter, notNullFilter);
var createIndexOptions = new CreateIndexOptions<User>
{
    Unique = true,
    Name = UniqueDoctorIdIndexName,
    PartialFilterExpression = andFilter,
};
var uniqueDoctorIdIndex = new CreateIndexModel<User>(
    uniqueDoctorIdIndexDefinition,
    createIndexOptions);

users.Indexes.CreateOne(uniqueDoctorIdIndex);
```

Probably in your description of a 'User' entity you must directly specify the BsonType of the 'DoctorId' field, by using an attribute, for example in our case it was:

```
[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
public Guid? DoctorId { get; set; }
```

I am more than sure that there is a more proficient and compact solution for this problem, so would be happy if somebody suggests it here.